# Parsing unicode characters in JSON using Python

Tags: python, c++, json, nlohmann-json

I'm working on to read data from JSON but JSON parser unable to decode some unicode characters. Below is the JSON data in the file I want to parse.

```
[  
    {  
        "code":"BR",
        "name":"Brazil",
        "capital":"Bras\xc3\xadlia"
    }
]
```

This data is in JSON file and I'm using **nlohmann json** library to parse the JSON. Below is the code that I am using.

```py
std::ifstream ifs("resources/countries.json");
nlohmann::json j2 = nlohmann::json::parse(ifs)
```

I get the following error

```
unknown character after backslash 'Bras\x'
```

Comment: I guess you should tell your stream that it shall decode the (obvious) utf-8 encoded input to unicode.  If I do this manually in Python3: `json.loads(b'"Bras\xc3\xadlia"'.decode('utf8'))`, then the result is the expected `'Brasília'`.  So all you need to do is convert the utf-8-encoded byte stream to a proper unicode string and json-parse this.  Json itself cannot handle the backslash-x sequence, in case this is verbatim in your input.  So whoever produced this did not produce a proper json then.

Comment: JSON uses `u\____`, not `\x__`. This will be a bit of a work to handle, but it's fairly straightforward. Decode the `\x` bytes, convert the UTF-8 to produce a Unicode codepoint, prefix '\u` and you're done.